# How do I use scikit-learn properly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, utf-8, package, importerror

```
from sklearn import linear_model
```

***This is the error that I got.. I thought maybe I should uninstall and try to install the scikit-learn package again..

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a6ebbebad697> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn import linear_model

C:\Users\Müco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\__init__.py in <module>()
     13 
     14 from .bayes import BayesianRidge, ARDRegression
---> 15 from .least_angle import (Lars, LassoLars, lars_path, LarsCV, LassoLarsCV,
     16                           LassoLarsIC)
     17 from .coordinate_descent import (Lasso, ElasticNet, LassoCV, ElasticNetCV,

C:\Users\Müco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\least_angle.py in <module>()
     23 from ..base import RegressorMixin
     24 from ..utils import arrayfuncs, as_float_array, check_X_y
---> 25 from ..model_selection import check_cv
     26 from ..exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
     27 from ..externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed

C:\Users\Müco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from ._split import BaseCrossValidator
      2 from ._split import KFold
      3 from ._split import GroupKFold
      4 from ._split import StratifiedKFold
      5 from ._split import TimeSeriesSplit

C:\Users\Müco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in <module>()
     23 import numpy as np
     24 
---> 25 from scipy.misc import comb
     26 from ..utils import indexable, check_random_state, safe_indexing
     27 from ..utils.validation import _num_samples, column_or_1d

ImportError: cannot import name 'comb'
```

but then I have this error in my command-prompt..

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 46: invalid start byte
```

I've been searching the internet for couple of hours but couldn't find anything useful.. any idea?

These are the lines that I've used;

```
pip uninstall numpy scipy -y
pip uninstall scikit-learn -y
```

then conda..

```
conda uninstall numpy scipy scikit-learn -y
```

then reinstall them again

```
conda install numpy scipy scikit-learn -y
```

Comment: Try to open prompt in admin mode and install it again.

Comment: Can you double check you data for non-ansi character as you are getting the error about `UnicodeDecodeError` but strange enough you also get the `ImportError`